# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}(M_k-M_{k-1})$ is a martingale

Tags: conditional-expectation, martingales

This is a problem from UMD probability quals [here](https://www-math.umd.edu/images/pdfs/quals/Probability/Probability-PhD-August-2021.pdf). I'm stuck in showing the conditional expectation requirement of a martingale. The problem is

> Let $(\Omega,F,\{F_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}},P)$ be a filtered space and let $\{M_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$be a $\{F_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$-martingale which is bounded in $L^\infty(\Omega,F,P)$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we define
> $$X_n := \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}(M_k-M_{k-1})$$
>
> 1. Show that $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a $\{F_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$-martingale.
> 2. Prove that $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges $P$-almost surely and in $L^2(\Omega,F,P)$

Solution: Part 2 is answered in a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287263/exercise-martingales-convergence-problem?rq=1). To answer part 1, we need to check the defintion of a martingale, i.e. check the following three requirements:

1. $X_n$ is $F_n$-measurable for every $n$. This is true because (i) $M_k$ is $F_k$ measurable and $F_k\subset F_n$ for all $k\leq n$ since $F$ is a filtration and so (ii) $X_n$ is a linear combination of $F_n$ measurable terms.
2. $\mathbb{E}|X_n|<\infty$ for all $n$. This is also not hard to show: Apply triangle inequality twice, and use the fact that $\mathbb{E}|M_k|<\infty$ for all $k$ since $M_k$ are martingales.
   $$\begin{eqnarray}
   \mathbb{E}|X_n| &=& \mathbb{E}|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}(M_k-M_{k-1})|\\
   &\leq & \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\mathbb{E}|M_k-M_{k-1}| \\
   &\leq & \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}(\mathbb{E}|M_k|+\mathbb{E}|M_{k-1}|)<\infty
   \end{eqnarray}$$
3. $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|F_n)= X_n$. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: The sequence $X_n$ is the martingale transform of $M_n$ by a deterministic (and hence predictable) sequence, so is itself a martingale.

Comment: By the definition of $X_n$, $X_{n+1} = X_n + \frac{1}{n+1}(M_{n+1}-M_n)$. Then $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{n+1} \mid F_n\right] = X_n + \frac{1}{n+1}\mathbb{E}\left[M_{n+1} - M_n\mid F_n\right] = X_n$. As $X_n,M_n$ are $F_n$-measurable and $\mathbb{E}\left[M_{n+1}\mid F_n\right] = M_n$.